# $R/(a)$ is torsion for any nonzero $a \in R$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $a \in R$ be nonzero. The claim now is that $R/(a)$ is a torsion $R$-module, where $(a) = Ra = \{ ra: r \in R\}$ is a cyclic submodule.

I don't know why I still cannot formulate a proof. I've read Foote and Dummit and some notes I found online, all of which seems to regard it as trivial so there's got to be something small I've missed. Here's my attempt:

*Attempt*. We prove by contradiction. Suppose $R/(a)$ is not torsion. Then there exists $r + (a) \in R/(a)$, such that for any nonzero $s \in R$, we have
$$s \cdot (r + (a)) = sr + (a) \neq 0_R + (a).$$
Accordingly, this means that $sr \notin (a)$ and $sr \neq 0_R $. And here's where I am stuck.

I was thinking of putting it into a form where I can use that $R$ is an integral domain, but I have $rs \neq 0$ and not $rs = 0$. I have spent hours on this, so it would be helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a typical element $r+(a)$. Then $a(r+(a)) = ra+(a) = 0$ as $ra \in (a)$.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed that I missed such an obvious observation. Thank you!

Comment: @devianceee It happens to all of us! No shame in it.